# Deleting child nodes in treeView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, treeview

There's my code:

```
private void removeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
    {
         if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null) treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
         else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Count == 1) treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Remove();
         else treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
    }
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
     if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent != null)
     {
         var xElement = (from q in doc.Elements("dogs").Elements("dog")
                        where q.Attribute("id").Value == treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString()
                        select q);
            foreach (var a in xElement)
                a.Remove();
            doc.Save("test.xml");
}
```

I want to search through my file for `id` value and if program will find it, it compares it to tag of selected node, and if it finds it, it'll delete this node. And everytime I'm trying to delete any node, error `NullReferenceException was unhandled` appears.

Comment: Imagine `treeView1.SelectedNode == null` in this case you'll be testing `if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent != null)`. What happens when you test a `**null** values.Parent ?` :) Can you debug this and give more information on exactly which variable is null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
```

This will either set your treeView1.SelectedNode to null or set the SelectedNode to the removed node's parent or to the next available node.

Also this code will set the parent, of the node you removed, to null. These two cases are likely the root cause of your exception. I would suggest simply setting a temporary variable to point to the node you want removed:

```
TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
```

Then simply change your code to:

```
TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null) 
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
    else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Count == 1) 
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Remove();
    else 
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
}

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var xElement = (from q in doc.Elements("dogs").Elements("dog")
                where q.Attribute("id").Value == node.Tag.ToString()
                select q);
foreach (var a in xElement)
    a.Remove();
doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Comment: Why unnecessarily you're setting node = `treeView1.SelectedNode;` twice? and OP has used  `if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent != null)` you've replaced with `if(node != null)` did you mean `if(node != null && node.Parent!=null)`

Comment: Ahh. My applogies, I missed that when I wrote the post. I'll edit it. Thank you for the notice.

Comment: Sure. The reason I changed that portion of code is that the OP wishes to remove the corresponding information from their XML file, however, the Parent Property of the node will be equal to null once Remove() is called on the SelectedNode. Thus the if statement will never be equal to true. Its possible that the OP wishes to check the current selected node's parent (which will either be null or an unrelated node), but I don't think that is the intent of the code.

Comment: You're right, when I'll delete node, there will be no `SelectedNode`. Before modifying this code, I've had a reason to maintain two `if`s, but now it's just redundant, so I moved second `if` at the beggining, where `SelectedNode` still has value. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome PotatoBox. I'm glad I could help. I'll edit my code to reflect your design decision.